# RUN pip install not working in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, psycopg2

i am stuck with this problem since several hours. I am trying to install psycopg2-binary via my Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest

RUN pip install psycopg2-binary

COPY Spark.py /app/Spark.py

COPY postgres-jdbc-driver.jar /app/postgres-jdbc-driver.jar
ENV SPARK_CLASSPATH=/app/postgres-jdbc-driver.jar


CMD ["python", "/app/Spark.py"]
```

But it does not install it. When i look in my docker container "pip list" i dondt see the package there. Any idea why? When i install it manually to my docker "pip install psycopg2-binary" it is working.

This is my Dockercompose file

```
  jupyter-pyspark-notebook:
    build:
      context: .  
      dockerfile: ./DockerfileSpark  
    hostname: jupyter-pyspark-notebook
    container_name: jupyter-pyspark-notebook
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./Spark.py:/app/Spark.py
    command: sh -c "sleep 40 && python /app/Spark.py"
```

This is the error i get which makes sense because there is not psycopg2-binary installed in the container. But why is it not installing. I have no idea ...

```
File "/app/Spark.py", line 3, in <module>
2023-10-31 11:46:22     import psycopg2
2023-10-31 11:46:22 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Comment: can you run "docker-compose build --no-cache" then, docker-compose up and send us output?

Comment: Now i dont receive any errors. I am learning docker atm and thought that it is enough to just do "docker-compose up" to initialise the build. But as mentioned from you with the "docker-compose build --no-cache" it is working now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is caching problem.

please run

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up
```

Comment: The hyphen on docker-compose is no longer required

Comment: Not an important thing :)